# Need to call a stored procedure from an AWS GLUE job

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to run a GLUE job and the stored procedure code starts. I have a SQL stored procedure and want to call it in the autogenerated pyspark code for the GLUE job. I don't want to use redshift or snowflake or anything like that if it can be helped. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you define what you mean by stored procedure?  A glue job is just python code so as long as the "stored procedure" is python code, it can be part of a the glue job.

Comment: The sp is written as a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

AWS GLUE actually runs a python code. You can put your logic in the python code and input this to glue on the AWS Console. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: If I include the auto-generated code, would I just input the sp code somewhere in that? ie insert ```CREATE PROCEDURE...END``` just in the actual script?